# Date ranges in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm having trouble coming up with this solution logically. I have an `accounts` table with a datetime `trial_expiration_date` column. I'd like to return all accounts that have been expired for at least two weeks but no more than one month using this column. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Two weeks mean 14 days past from current date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. Just select all records where the expiration date is between two weeks ago and one month ago.

```
select * 
from accounts 
where trial_expiration_date between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    and DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this..

```
select *
from TABLE
where trial_expiration_date between dateadd(day,-14,getdate()) and getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
select *
from t
where 
     datediff(date_add(trial_expiration_date, interval 2 week), now()) < 0
     and
     datediff(date_add(trial_expiration_date, interval 1 month), now()) > 0
```

It only calculate the `date` parts only and does not consider `time`.